# Vertically Align Text on google spreadsheet via google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to figure out how to align text in the middle vertically.  According to the documentation I have found my following example should work:

```
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(form.getDestinationId()); 
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var fullRange = sheet.getRange("A1:Z1001");

fullRange.setHorizontalAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
fullRange.setVerticalAlignment(DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
```

The interesting thing I find is that the Horizontal Alignment works, but the vertical one does not.  Am I possibly using out dated methods?  Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `middle` as the parameter for [setVerticalAlignment()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setverticalalignmentalignment) :

```
fullRange.setHorizontalAlignment("center").setVerticalAlignment("middle");
```

You're using the [Enum for the DocumentApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/vertical-alignment) intended for Google Docs tables and cells and you're using Spreadsheets.