# How set Alignment for range on google spreadsheet with google-script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello i want to set a center alignment on a range with google script but i don't know how can i do it.

I have already tried

`sheet_destination.getRange(last_row_desti+1,1,1,4).setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);`

but the element setAlignment doesn't exist on a range

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39214558/vertically-align-text-on-google-spreadsheet-via-google-script) can help you 

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s= ss.getActiveSheet()
  var lr = s.getLastRow()
  var r= s.getRange(1, 1, lr,4)
  var set=r.setHorizontalAlignment("center")
}
```

Reference: [setHorizontalAlignment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setHorizontalAlignment(String))